# Apply shade on a range of cells based on the value in another cell range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2010 sheet with dates for every month of the year (B8:B38). In (A8:A38) I use `weekday()` to show the weekdays as text.

Now, I would like to color only the rows in the range (A8:W38) showing `Saturday` & `Sundays` 50% grey.

I tried conditional formatting with no luck. Might be because in each cell (A8:A38) I have a formula (weekday()) not a text (Mo, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, or Sun).

Any suggestion highly appreciated. Thank you all! :=) 
Stevas

Comment: `weekday()` returns numbers for each weekday. In default `sunday = 1` and `saturday = 7` use these numbers for conditional formatting.

Comment: @Stevas if you liked my answer then please accept it as an answer doing the green tick. I need the points : 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this if you have to use VBA:-

```
    Option Explicit

        Sub ColourDays()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim c As Range

        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = ws.Range("A8:W38")

        For Each c In rng
        If c.Value = "Sat" Then

        With c.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

        Else
        If c.Value = "Sun" Then

        With c.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
        End If
        Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot recommend doing this with VBA. Conditional formatting is much easier and more efficient than a VBA code can be.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Agreed but he asked for VBA so gave him VBA!

Comment: Just wanted to note that. Didn't say it is wrong, just think there was a more efficient way do yo id. • For your interest even with VBA you could apply the conditional formatting. So it would be much more dynamic and not a static format but still using VBA.

Comment: Thank you Peh, I do not have to do it with VBA, but for some reason I could not get it right with conditiona formating. Nothing happened when I tried it...